# CoreException: Could not calculate build plan

Tags: java, maven

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>openam-sso-sample</artifactId>
    <groupId>me.batizhao</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>agent-java</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Java client for OpenAM Agent</name>

<build>
    <finalName>agent-java</finalName>
</build>

</project>
```

but getting error at `<packaging>` tag:

```
CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 
(C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-compiler-plugin\2.3.2\maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)    pom.xml /agent-java line 15 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

Comment: Which command are you using?

Comment: I would suggest to try to delete the whole local repository under Users\Administrator\.m2/repository and retry the whole build.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the .m2 - directory in my home folder fixed exactly this problem for me once. Run
`mvn install` in your project's root after that to recreate the folder with the correct dependencies.

Comment: As you suggested, I tried deleting the .m2 directory in my home folder and running 'mvn install' in my project folder. I got the error message, 'zsh: command not found: mvn." Do I need to install mvn separately? Or does it come with Eclipse and Java?